# Delete multiple chrome profile automatically

Tags: python, google-chrome

So I made a bot to do some task with google chrome and it created many google chrome profile. And now I am done with that task so I want to delete all my created google chrome profile.

NB:

- I already deleted the profile folder in `%LOCALappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data`. The folder successfully deleted but the profile still appear in chrome startup window.

[image: A lot of chrome profile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need help with this, I made a PowerShell script that removes Google Chrome's profile data.

It stops any chrome processes currently running, then targets:

- Profile # and Default directories
- Local State file

Located in:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`

```
$UserData = "$($env:LOCALAPPDATA)\Google\Chrome\User Data"

$Folders = Get-ChildItem $UserData | Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq "Default" -or $_.Name -like "Profile*"}

$FoldersFullPath = $Folders.FullName 


if ($Null -ne (get-process 'chrome' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
    stop-process -ProcessName 'chrome'
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
}

$FoldersFullPath | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Path -Path $_){
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Path $_
    }
}

if (Test-Path -Path "$UserData\Local state"){
    Remove-Item -Path "$UserData\Local state"
}
```

I'm sure you can use this to help you re-create it in Python, in fact, this is a good excuse to learn Python myself.